# Display Positive Infinity in console

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

Simply speaking console displays positive infinity as `?` instead of `∞`. Example code:

```cs
var a = double.PositiveInfinity;
Console.WriteLine(a); //displays ? instead of ∞
```

I have tried using Invariant Culture, `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`, and `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`. Always displays `?`.

P.S

Writing it to a file does work and it displays correctly, but it would be nice if it also displayed properly on console.

Comment: What platform??

Comment: @DanielA.White Windows 10, .net 6.0.

Comment: Does it show like you'd expect if you use Windows Terminal if you're currently using the old `cmd` console host instead?

Comment: @MartinCostello doesn't work when launched through Visual Studio 2022, doesn't work in Windows Terminal either. The same about cmd.

Comment: Setting `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` worked on my machine. I think it might depend on the codepage used by console and maybe font.

Comment: @MikeMozhaev I guess I will look into it further, but it means I'm on the right track.

Comment: Unicode Encoding is not enough. The Console **Font** needs to support the specific glyph, too.  => https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/mathematical_operators/fontsupport.htm In my Windows 10 the default font is Consolas. Assuming yours is, too: it only supports 7% of that block.

Comment: Funny enough, it lists "infinity" (U+221E) as supported ... strange. AND prints it. What's your font?

Comment: When i try on my linux machine, all work fine. It display ∞. Maybe the encoded char in your cmd. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388500/9455573)

Comment: Does running `chcp 65001` beforehand work?